# I cant assign value from databse to text box

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am doing a search operation ,ie search customers by customer name.I have text box ,when type fist letter on text,with auto complete function in jquery list all customer name that match the letter.We can select wanted name from that.I want get  the id  of customer form customer table in another text box.

My table is customer

```
customer 

id    name

1      neenu

2      nitha

3      nisha

4       sitha
```

i have two pages payment_verification.php and suggest_field.php

payment_verification.php

```
<script>
 function auto(tab,field,id){
 var point='#'+id;
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 $(point).autocomplete({source:'suggest_field.php?
 field='+field+'&table='+tab,    minLength:1});
  });
    }


 </script>   

 <input name="cust_name1" id="name" 
 onFocus="auto('customer','name','name')"     type="text" />

 <input name="cust_id" id="cust_id"    type="text"  vale=""/>
```

In auto function first paramer is table name,second parmeter is field name,third parameter is id of that text box.

suggest_field.php

```
 <?php
 require_once("codelibrary/inc/variables.php");
 require_once("codelibrary/inc/functions.php");
 if ( !isset($_REQUEST['term']) )
 exit;
 $field=$_GET['field'];
 $table=$_GET['table'];


 $qry='select distinct '.$field.' from '.$table.'
 where '.$field.' like "'.     mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']) .'%"  
 order  by '.$field.' asc';
 $rs = mysql_query($qry);
 $data = array();
 if ( $rs && mysql_num_rows($rs) )
 {
  while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($rs, MYSQL_ASSOC) )
   {
    $data[] = array(
        'value' => $row[$field]
    );
 }
}
echo json_encode($data);
flush();
 ?>
```

I got customer name in first text box,i want to get the customer's id in second text box.
Any misunderstanding in my question sorry.

Comment: whats the problem in getting customer name ? and your query is widely open for sql injection

Comment: I got customer name,but want to get also the customer id and sign that to second text box with textbox id cust_id

Comment: since you are using jquery than  whats the problem in using `("#cuscust_id").val()` ? (check this http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Comment: now query is used to get the customer name,dont get customer id,,

Comment: take customer id from databse and assign it to second text box,this is my need

Comment: so you want to assign the customer id to text box from database and later wants to take ? am i correct ?

Comment: if you wants to do that .... than you can not get the id by php either you have to use javascript like  $(".class_of_custiner_id).attr('id'); and assign to hidden text field than get it on form submit ... btw if its really eCommerce application than you should not query like that ...

Comment: Friend...how changes need on suggest_field.php ie my query side

Comment: i would highly recommended you to read http://shiflett.org/articles